# minecraft forge java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple entries with same key

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm modding minecraft, and it gives me this error when i put it in the "mods" folder and launch it with forge.

```java
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple entries with same key: wm=FMLMod:wm{1.0 Beta} and wm=FMLMod:wm{1.0 Beta}. To index multiple values under a key, use Multimaps.index.
```

Windows Home 64-Bit
Forge for 1.12.2
Eclipse IDE

Comment: That error message is pretty descriptive.  Have you followed its advice?

Comment: Yes, I only used it once though, I don't see where it is twice?

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: Or, y'know, use Multimaps.index.

Comment: Where would I use multimaps.index in my code? Theres like 3 files that have the "wm" id

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: https://hastebin.com/utamoperob.css <--- Main.java (hastebin says its css)
https://hastebin.com/fujagemuho.java <-- Reference.java
https://imgur.com/a/cBUJtN7 <--- Structure View

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218371/discussion-between-aawesome-and-robert-harvey).

Comment: Is there another mod with the mod ID `wm`?

Comment: nope @TheKingElessar